# Android: Toggle Button OnPress state

Tags: android, selector, drawable, state

I have a `ToggleButton` which has a `selector` `backgroundDrawable`. The ON and OFF state work perfectly fine, i.e. they change colour as I want them to. However, I am trying to colour the `Togglebutton` when it is pressed, i.e. touched AND not released.

`selector`:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_unselected_background"
      android:state_checked="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_highlighted_background"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_unselected_background"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

that's the code I use for any button selector I'm using, always works like a charm, suit yourself :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<!-- Button Focused-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/plus_icon_pressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" />
<!-- Button Focused Pressed-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/plus_icon_pressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!-- Button Pressed-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/plus_icon_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!-- Button Default Image-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/plus_icon" />


</selector>
```

Comment: I've pasted your code in and trying it out. In the meantime, could you define what each state does? I know the states are right there in front of me but it's still not clear as to which item is for which "humanly-perceived" state, i.e. It's being pressed etc. Like, focus is meant for track-ball devices. And my app doesn't obviously target any of them. What i'm after really is a 'OnHover" state.

Comment: I even wrote you comments :) the pressed is "pressed" of course, as in quick press (touch down and up), and focused are when you put your finger on the button for a long press. default is unpressed state.

Comment: That's exactly what i've done. Only the quick touch (down and up) and the default state is working. The focused states (e.g. long press) aren't working at all.

Comment: weird, I used that exact code for more time then i can remember, always working..

check your button xml, maybe you're doing something wrong, I don't see any problem in the selector.

Comment: Thank you @JozeRi. Your answer lead me on the straight path! +1

Answer (score 1):

The following worked as it accounts for all states. Since I was working with a `ToggleButton`, I needed the `checked` state too:

```
<!-- Button Focused-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_highlighted_background" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" />
<!-- Button Focused Pressed-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_highlighted_background" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!-- Button Pressed-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_highlighted_background" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!-- Button Pressed-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_selected_background" android:state_checked="true" />
<!-- Button Default Image-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/category_unselected_background" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example :), too on [here](http://www.nosinmiubuntu.com/estilizando-togglebutton-en-android/)

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" /> //currently pressed turning the toggle on
            <item android:state_pressed="true" /> //currently pressed turning the toggle off
            <item android:state_checked="true" /> //not pressed default checked state
            <item /> //default non-pressed non-checked
        </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Button Touch-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- Button ON-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_background_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- Button Default Image-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Please add some description to make others understand. :)